# Cannot read property 'roles' of null. When adding roles to a user upon joining a server

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

So basically I just need it to add the role and the bot has permissions and the role is there. The full console is as follows

````
(c) 2020 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\Users\thato\Desktop\Deku>node .
sequelize deprecated String based operators are now deprecated. Please use Symbol based operators for better security, read more at http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/querying.html#operators node_modules\sequelize\lib\sequelize.js:245:13
═[Discord-Leveling Database Loaded -V1.1.0]═[Support server: https://discord.gg/eBFKDbx]=
Loading...
D3ku is online!
New member joined server, successfully sent a message!
New member joined server, successfully sent a message!
C:\Users\thato\Desktop\Deku\index.js:358
    let DaRole = message.guild.roles.cache.find(r => r.name === 'Human')
                               ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'roles' of null
    at Client.<anonymous> (C:\Users\thato\Desktop\Deku\index.js:358:32)
    at Client.emit (events.js:326:22)
    at MessageCreateAction.handle (C:\Users\thato\Desktop\Deku\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\actions\MessageCreate.js:31:14)
    at Object.module.exports [as MESSAGE_CREATE] (C:\Users\thato\Desktop\Deku\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\handlers\MESSAGE_CREATE.js:4:32)

(HERE WAS A BUNCH OF RANDOM ERRORS NO ONE NEEDS)

C:\Users\thato\Desktop\Deku>```

I really can\'t get it to send immediately either. It only sends the welcome message when the user sends a message in the server. That\'s also when the error finally appears.
````

Comment: To ask in a clearly way it's impor add son code minimum reproducible, please try to add at least what is message, what's the structure of that object

Comment: We cannot help you unless you provide some code.

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is stating that `message.guild` is `null`. This can happen on partial messages or messages from DMs.

If the message is a partial, `message.partial` would be `true`. To fetch the rest of the message, run `message.fetch().then(fullmessage => {...})`.

`message.channel.type === 'dm'` can tell you if the message is from a DM.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you adding

```
if(message.channel.type === 'dm') return message.reply('This command does not work in DMs')
```

to the beginning of the command and it should prevent this.